# NHibernate find

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have a 'Customer' table with 'FirstName' and 'LastName' columns. I have to execute a search on the 'Customer' table after 'FirstName', 'LastName' and 'FirstName + LastName' depending on a TextBox text. What's the besty way/query to implement this using NHibernate or SQL query?

Comment: can you show me an example. Not everybody as so clever like you are

Answer (score 1):

using HQl that would be simple

```
var session = SessionFactory.OpenSession;
var transaction = session.BeginTransaction;
var query = session.CreateQuery("FROM Customer c WHERE c.LastName = :LastName And c.FirstName = :FirstName");
query.SetString("FirstName", FirstName);
query.SetString("LastName", LastName);
var returnList = _Query.List(Of Customer)();
transaction.Commit();
```

Of course that is presumming that you have an object called Customer and that it is mapped correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use QueryOver. It is also type safe:

```
IList<Customer> customers =
session.QueryOver<Customer>()
    .Where(c => c.LastName == "Foo" && c.FirstName == "Bar")
    .List();
```

Requirements:

- Customer entity class (mapped)
- Open Session to the DB

Answer (score 0):

```js
var query = this.CreateQuery(@"select c.LastName,c.FirstName from Customer  as c where c.LastName = :LastName And c.FirstName = :FirstName").SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean<Customer>());
query.SetParameter("FirstName", FirstName);
query.SetParameter("LastName", LastName);
var result = query.List<Customer>().ToList();
return result;
```